# Pre-fill TextBox in UserForm with values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open a `TextBox1` in `UserForm1` in `VBA` and `pre-fill` the `TextBox` with the values `"123"`. 
Therefore I tried to go with the following `VBA` options:

```
Private Sub textbox()
TextBox1.Text = "123"
End Sub


Private Sub textbox()
TextBox1.Value = "123"
End Sub
```

However, none of them worked. 
Do you have any idea how I can `pre-fill` it?

Comment: Check out the Userform_Initialize event

Comment: `UserForm1.TextBox1.text = "123"`? If not that You can do this in properties of `Textbox1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the `UserForm1` in the VBE and select view code. Then copy into the window the following code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.TextBox1.Value = "123"

End Sub
```

Afterwards, you may press `F5` or select `Run Macro` from the the `Run` menu.